# How to implement calculator's logic

Tags: android

I created a calculator but it crashes every time I click *,/,+,- twice. I know it crashes because you can't divide/multiply twice, but how do I set a rule that it will check whether if the multiply/divide is already clicked once?

Here's the code:

```
package com.example.calculator;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button add1, add2, add3, add4, add5, add6, add7, add8, add9, 
            plus, minus, divide, multiply, equal, add0, clear;
    TextView Display, infobox;
    String x;
    double plusminus, firstDouble, secondDouble, totalDouble;
    boolean plusClick, minusClick, multiplyClick, divideClick;
    int checkMulti = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.calculator);
        initialize();
    }

    void initialize() {
        add0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b0);
        // snipped cases for 1 to 8
        add9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b9);
        minus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub);
        equal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bEquals);
        plus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
        clear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bClear);
        Display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResults);
        divide = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bDivide);
        multiply = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bMultiply);
        add0.setOnClickListener(this);
        // snipped cases for 1 to 8
        add9.setOnClickListener(this);
        minus.setOnClickListener(this);
        equal.setOnClickListener(this);
        plus.setOnClickListener(this);
        Display.setOnClickListener(this);
        divide.setOnClickListener(this);
        multiply.setOnClickListener(this);
        clear.setOnClickListener(this);
    }    
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {       
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.b0:
            Display.setText(Display.getText() + "0");
            break;
            // ... snipped cases for 1 to 8
            case R.id.b9:
            Display.setText(Display.getText() + "9");
            break;
            case R.id.bAdd:
            firstDouble = (Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(Display.getText())));
            Display.setText("");
            plusClick = true;
            break;  
            case R.id.bSub:
            firstDouble = (Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(Display.getText())));
            Display.setText("");
            minusClick = true;      
            break;
            case R.id.bEquals:
            secondDouble = (Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(Display.getText())));
            if (plusClick) {
                totalDouble = firstDouble + secondDouble;
                Display.setText((String.valueOf(totalDouble)));
                firstDouble = 0;
                secondDouble = 0;
                plusClick = false;
            }

            if (minusClick) {
                totalDouble = firstDouble - secondDouble;
                Display.setText((String.valueOf(totalDouble)));
                firstDouble = 0;
                secondDouble = 0;
                minusClick = false;
            }           

            if (divideClick) {
                totalDouble = firstDouble / secondDouble;
                Display.setText((String.valueOf(totalDouble)));
                firstDouble = 0;
                secondDouble=0;
                divideClick = false;
            }

            if (multiplyClick) {
                totalDouble = firstDouble * secondDouble;
                Display.setText((String.valueOf(totalDouble)));
                firstDouble = 0;
                secondDouble = 0;
                multiplyClick = false;
            }
            break;      

            case R.id.bMultiply:    
            firstDouble = (Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(Display.getText())));
            Display.setText("");
            multiplyClick = true;
            break;

            case R.id.bDivide:
            firstDouble = (Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(Display.getText())));
            Display.setText("");
            divideClick = true;             
            break;

            case R.id.bClear:
            Display.setText("");
            multiplyClick = false;
            divideClick = false;
            plusClick = false;
            minusClick = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

If I'm not mistaken it should be something like this

```
        case R.id.bMultiply:
        if (Display.getText() != "") {
            firstDouble = (Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(Display.getText())));
            Display.setText("");
            multiplyClick = true;
        }
        break;

        case R.id.bDivide:
        if (Display.getText() != null) {
            firstDouble = (Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(Display.getText())));
            Display.setText("");
            divideClick = true;         
        }
        break;
```

LogCat (beginning 07-26 09:00:00):

```
04:02.361: E/AndroidRuntime(5387): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04:02.361: E/AndroidRuntime(5387): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
04:02.361: E/AndroidRuntime(5387):  at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
04:02.361: E/AndroidRuntime(5387):  at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:248)
04:02.361: E/AndroidRuntime(5387):  at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:295)
04:02.361: E/AndroidRuntime(5387):  at com.example.calculator.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:177)
04:02.361: E/AndroidRuntime(5387):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4162)
04:02.361: E/AndroidRuntime(5387):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17082)
04:02.361: E/AndroidRuntime(5387):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
04:02.361: E/AndroidRuntime(5387):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04:02.361: E/AndroidRuntime(5387):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04:02.361: E/AndroidRuntime(5387):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4856)
04:02.361: E/AndroidRuntime(5387):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04:02.361: E/AndroidRuntime(5387):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04:02.361: E/AndroidRuntime(5387):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
04:02.361: E/AndroidRuntime(5387):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
04:02.361: E/AndroidRuntime(5387):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04:10.429: I/Process(5387): Sending signal. PID: 5387 SIG: 9
19:01.891: D/libEGL(6671): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
19:01.901: D/libEGL(6671): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
19:01.911: D/libEGL(6671): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
19:01.961: D/OpenGLRenderer(6671): Enabling debug mode 0
19:04.403: D/AndroidRuntime(6671): Shutting down VM
19:04.403: W/dalvikvm(6671): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x418972a0)
19:04.433: E/AndroidRuntime(6671): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
19:04.433: E/AndroidRuntime(6671): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
19:04.433: E/AndroidRuntime(6671):  at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
19:04.433: E/AndroidRuntime(6671):  at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:248)
19:04.433: E/AndroidRuntime(6671):  at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:295)
19:04.433: E/AndroidRuntime(6671):  at com.example.calculator.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:168)
19:04.433: E/AndroidRuntime(6671):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4162)
19:04.433: E/AndroidRuntime(6671):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17082)
19:04.433: E/AndroidRuntime(6671):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
19:04.433: E/AndroidRuntime(6671):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
19:04.433: E/AndroidRuntime(6671):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
19:04.433: E/AndroidRuntime(6671):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4856)
19:04.433: E/AndroidRuntime(6671):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
19:04.433: E/AndroidRuntime(6671):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
19:04.433: E/AndroidRuntime(6671):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
19:04.433: E/AndroidRuntime(6671):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
19:04.433: E/AndroidRuntime(6671):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
20:27.315: D/AndroidRuntime(6893): Shutting down VM
20:27.315: W/dalvikvm(6893): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x418972a0)
20:27.325: E/AndroidRuntime(6893): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
20:27.325: E/AndroidRuntime(6893): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
20:27.325: E/AndroidRuntime(6893):  at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
20:27.325: E/AndroidRuntime(6893):  at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:248)
20:27.325: E/AndroidRuntime(6893):  at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:295)
20:27.325: E/AndroidRuntime(6893):  at com.example.calculator.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:168)
20:27.325: E/AndroidRuntime(6893):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4162)
20:27.325: E/AndroidRuntime(6893):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17082)
20:27.325: E/AndroidRuntime(6893):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
20:27.325: E/AndroidRuntime(6893):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
20:27.325: E/AndroidRuntime(6893):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
20:27.325: E/AndroidRuntime(6893):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4856)
20:27.325: E/AndroidRuntime(6893):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
20:27.325: E/AndroidRuntime(6893):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
20:27.325: E/AndroidRuntime(6893):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
20:27.325: E/AndroidRuntime(6893):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
20:27.325: E/AndroidRuntime(6893):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
23:16.225: D/AndroidRuntime(7204): Shutting down VM
23:16.225: W/dalvikvm(7204): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x418972a0)
23:16.245: E/AndroidRuntime(7204): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
23:16.245: E/AndroidRuntime(7204): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
23:16.245: E/AndroidRuntime(7204):  at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
23:16.245: E/AndroidRuntime(7204):  at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:248)
23:16.245: E/AndroidRuntime(7204):  at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:295)
23:16.245: E/AndroidRuntime(7204):  at com.example.calculator.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:176)
23:16.245: E/AndroidRuntime(7204):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4162)
23:16.245: E/AndroidRuntime(7204):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17082)
23:16.245: E/AndroidRuntime(7204):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
23:16.245: E/AndroidRuntime(7204):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
23:16.245: E/AndroidRuntime(7204):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
23:16.245: E/AndroidRuntime(7204):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4856)
23:16.245: E/AndroidRuntime(7204):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
23:16.245: E/AndroidRuntime(7204):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
23:16.245: E/AndroidRuntime(7204):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
23:16.245: E/AndroidRuntime(7204):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
23:16.245: E/AndroidRuntime(7204):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What do you mean you can't divide/multiple twice? In almost all calculators you can. Hitting divide or multiply twice will simply recall the function on the current value.

Comment: As in if I hit the multiply/divide button without showing any values on the display screen twice it will crash

Comment: Check whether there are values first, before trying to do math with them. `try` .. `catch` is your friend here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You should also post your error log to understand why exactly is your program crashing.

2) It is probably crashing before you set Display.setText(""); Display to blank after you have down your calculation. If you press divide again the next time it will try to parse blanket to Double but it is empty "" so it crashes while parsing empty space. There could be other errors, you have to look at your error log.

3) In your if condition that you put up there you have to check if Display.getText().toString() is a valid number and not empty and greater than zero. but again look at your error log always to know why your app is crashing.

Comment: Updated, I tried Display.getText != null and Display.getText != "" but it still crashes..

Comment: it should be Display.getText().toString()!=""

Comment: on top of that you can use try catch to catch the exception. In this way at least your application will not crash and you can show error message yourself if user enters alphabets  instead of numbers.